# Не срабатывает jQuery при проверке

Tags: jquery

Не срабатывает  jQuery , проверяю запросом в body

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
 });
 </script>
```

Сообщение не вылезает. В чём может быть причина. Подключение к библиотекам вроде бы есть.

```
  <head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108903228-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-108903228-1');
</script>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cat/mobile/js/responsivemultimenu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cat/mobile/css/responsivemultimenu.css" type="text/css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Eycu05xpxlVEbZNodbRG1tbtk3XdjDymXQHh3EjFJuk" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/cat/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/cat/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#mega-menu-tut').dcMegaMenu({
        rowItems: '4',
        speed: 'fast'
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var mobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (mobile) { 
       document.getElementById('Smenu').style.display='none';
    } 
    else 
    { 

    }
</script> 

<link href="/cat/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 <meta name="mailru-domain" content="AIz2kXaUbxFiocEp" />   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://tdock.ru/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<meta name="theme-color" content="#3c404b">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1251">
<meta name="keywords" content="запчасти,в наличии, в краснодаре,техдок,под заказ,запчасти для ТО,каталоги, по вин коду">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hyundai Accent (BAFDP65) двиг. G4EC объем 1.5 л. 102 л.с. МКПП | Магазин автозапчастей Техдок </title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="X7MCF41GPBM2,X7MCF41GP5V0,X7MCF41GP4M0,X7MCF41GP9M2,X7MCF41GP8M2,X7MCF41GP7M0,X7MCF41GP5M0,X7MCF41GP8M1,X7MCF41GP6M0,X7MCF41GP7M1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Каталог запчастей для ТО Hyundai Accent (BAFDP65) двиг. G4EC объем 1.5 л. 102 л.с. МКПП X7MCF41GPBM241619" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-core/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-core/script/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-core/script/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-core/script/engine-script.js?protocol=http&amp;mgBaseDir=http://tdock.ru&amp;currency=руб.&amp;phoneMask=+7 (999) 999-99-99"></script>

    <!--Реестр определенных стилей в плагинах движка-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/faq/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/scrolltop/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/comments/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/mg-highlight/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--/Реестр определенных стилей в плагинах движка-->

    <!--Обязательный файл стилей для каждого шаблона-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tdock.ru/mg-templates/default/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!--/Обязательный файл стилей для каждого шаблона-->


    <!--Цветовая схема шаблона-->
    <link href="http://tdock.ru/mg-templates/default/css/color-scheme/color_DE0101.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--/Цветовая схема шаблона-->

    <!--Реестр определенных скриптов в плагинах движка-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/faq/js/faq.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/scrolltop/js/scrolltop.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/comments/js/comments.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-plugins/mg-highlight/js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-templates/default/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-templates/default/js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-templates/default/js/layout.cart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tdock.ru/mg-core/script/standard/js/layout.search.js"></script>
    <!--/Реестр определенных скриптов в плагинах движка-->


<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Eycu05xpxlVEbZNodbRG1tbtk3XdjDymXQHh3EjFJuk" />
<meta name="yandex-verification" content="96c76f3fcf1f76f1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mg-templates/default/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mg-templates/default/css/new_mobi.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mg-templates/default/css/footer_mobile.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mg-templates/default/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mg-templates/default/css/stylef.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/mg-templates/default/js/select.js"></script>


  </head>
```

Ошибки из консоли:

```
This page was loaded non-securely in an incognito mode browser. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see (здесь урл гугла stackoverflow ругается в комментарии его укажу ниже).
mobile.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
form.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
book.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
bg_black.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
script.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:79)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:3)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
mobile.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
form.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу ошибки из консоли.

Comment: Разместил, ссылка на которую ругался stackoverflow - https://goo.gl/y8SRRv

Comment: script.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - вот тут, полагаю, все и останавливается. надо лечить script.js

Comment: Вот тут камрады пишут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1